# Reactjs TextArea object is read only instead of mutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a TextArea object that will not allow new text to be entered. Initially I had tried this without the constructor, but would get areas when I would try to call my on change method because it was not bound to `this`. Adding the constructor to bind the onChange method disallows me from entering text.

```
        class TextAreaCounter extends React.Component{
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this._textChange = this._textChange.bind(this);
            }
            getInitialState() {
                return {
                    text: this.props.text,
                };
            }
            _textChange(ev) {
                this.setState({
                    text: ev.target.value,
                });
            }
            render() {
                return React.DOM.div(null,
                    React.DOM.textarea({
                        value: this.props.text,
                        onChange: this._textChange,
                    }),
                    React.DOM.h3(null, this.props.text.length)
                );
            }
        }
        TextAreaCounter.PropTypes = {
            text: React.PropTypes.string,
        }
        TextAreaCounter.defaultProps = {
            text: '',
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(TextAreaCounter, {
                text: "billy",
            }),
            document.getElementById("app")
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing this.state.text as the value to your textarea instead of this.props.text.

Comment: Correct! And I should set a state in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

First, I was using `this.props` instead of `this.state` in the render method. So, my onChange method was called but never actually updating.

Second, `getIntialState` is deprecated, so I update to a state object in the constructor.

```
       class TextAreaCounter extends React.Component{
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this._textChange = this._textChange.bind(this);
                this.state = {
                    text: this.props.text,
                };
            }
            _textChange(ev) {
                this.setState({
                    text: ev.target.value,
                });
            }
            render() {
                return React.DOM.div(null,
                    React.DOM.textarea({
                        value: this.state.text,
                        onChange: this._textChange,
                    }),
                    React.DOM.h3(null, this.state.text.length)
                );
            }
        }
```